# Azure Cognitive Search and Cosmos DB RUs consumption

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cognitive-search, azure-cognitive-services

In Azure Cognitive Search, when you **import data** from Cosmos DB, does it consume RUs?

Or do they  have a way to import the data without consuming RUs given that they're both Azure resources?

If it does consume RUs, is there a way to know in advance how much RUs it would take? or perhaps after each import can we get how many RUs were consumed for this action?

Comment: Anything running queries (or writes) against a Cosmos DB container will burn RUs. How many RU per operation... is anyone's guess - you'll need to try it out and benchmark/monitor it. Remember that calls will throttle if you don't have enough RU/second allocated for a particular action.

Answer (score 0):

Anything running queries or writes against a COSMOS DB Container will burn RU’S.

To reduce the RU Consumption for write operations, limit the number of indexed properties. Like for example data consistency: the strong and bounded staleness consistency levels consume approximately two times more RU’S  while performing read operations when compared to that of other relaxed consistency levels.

The best way to optimize or reduce the RU cost of write operations is to right size your items and the number of properties that get indexed. Storing very large items in Azure COSMOS DB results in high RU charges and can be considered as an Anti-pattern.

for more details please find the below links:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/request-units

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-index-cosmosdb